# Matlab - putting a square hole in a square plane

Tags: matlab

I have a square plane of size axa in Matlab (2D) and I want to create a meshgrid and put a hole in it of size bxb. My code seems to work, but looking closely it looks a bit strange. I'm new to Matlab.

The working code:

```
close all
clear all

a = 3;
b = 2;
number_of_gridcells = 150; % (both are the same since I will always have an outer square of axa)

% Create grid
wide = a; % m, plate width
high = a; % m, plate height

resX = number_of_gridcells; % number of grid points in X
resY = number_of_gridcells; % number of grid points in Y

[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:wide/resX:wide , 0:high/resY:high); % Creates a rectangular grid

% Remove an inner square of bxb
mask = abs(X - (a/2)) <= (b/2) & abs(Y - (a/2)) <= (b/2);

X(mask) = NaN;
Y(mask) = NaN;

% Initial condition (all equal)
Phi(1:resY+1,1:resX+1) = 0;
Phi0 = Phi; % initial condition preserved as Phi0

figure (1)
box on;
hold on;
set(gca,'FontSize',14);
lw = 1.5;
contourf(X, Y, Phi0, 20)
caxis([0 50])
colorbar('horiz')
axis equal
```

An example: for a=3 and b=2, I would expect a square of 3x3 with a wall thickness of 0.5.

[image]

This seems correct, but looking closer at the corners I see this:

[image]

First of all the corners are under an angle, while I was expecting just a 90 degree angle in the corners. Secondly, the corner starts at 0.5, but the wall itself is 0.48. So the wall is small than expected and thus the value for b is higher than expected.

I think it has something to do with how I create the mask in my code, but I am not sure how to fix this and if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: The values in ```Phi0``` should be correct, but ```contouf``` does this interpolation at the corners. Try to use for example ```surf``` instead.

Comment: Good comment! I did that and now I can see that one row of grid is missing. It seems that the cut out is too large for some reason.

Comment: Where you define the mask in your code, substitute ```<=``` with ```<```, then you should have your wall thickness of 0.5.

Comment: A that's it! And about the corner itself? You stated that 'contourf' always interpolates at the corners, so I should use surf. What is the purpose then of 'contourf' and 'surf'?

Comment: It's much easier to understand when you see the documentation for the functions https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html and https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html. While ```contour``` use ```Phi0``` to draw isolines ```surf``` maps just the values in ```Phi0``` to your defined grid.

Comment: Can you put this as an answer so I can close it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the definition of your mask should be:

```
mask = abs(X - (a/2)) < (b/2) & abs(Y - (a/2)) < (b/2);
```

Otherwise the NaNs will also "sit" on the edge of your wall.
And second if you want to visualize just a plain surface on a grid, use `surf()` or `surface()`.
`Contourf()` is used to draw isolines, that's why you see the rounded corner. The correct square hole should look like that:
[image: Square Hole]